# React js, pass a function with parameters as props without using this keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that has a save button. However, I can only define the saving function inside the Parent component. I need to pass the function as a props to the child component along with its parameters. All the methods I found uses .this, renders and constructors. I need a way using the modern react functions.

```
export function childComponent (props) {
    let { handleSave, item, list } = props;
    return ( 
        //Saves item in list
        <button className="palletSaveButton" onClick={handleSave(item, list)}> Save </button>
    )
}

const ParentComponent = () => {

    let list = [{...}];
    let item = {...};
    
    function handleSaveClick(item, list) {
        list.push(item)
    }
    
    return (
        <childComponent handleSave={() => handleSaveClick(item, list)} />
    );
}
```

Comment: You can do something  like this with the help of callbacks https://medium.com/@jasminegump/passing-data-between-a-parent-and-child-in-react-deea2ec8e654  , so you can send the new list from child to parent as callback

Comment: you can simply write `function handleSaveClick() { list.push(item) }` and `handleSave={handleSaveClick}` isn't it ?

Comment: @DeepakMukka the whole point of my question is that I don't understand how the this and render and constructors work.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé the function I have does more than push item in list, it calls an API. I can't write all that logic in the props

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is understanding if you want the `list` and `item` to ALWAYS be from the Parent as the source of truth, or if you are trying to pass those variables FROM the child TO the parent.

```
export function childComponent ({handleSave}) {
    return ( 
        //Saves item in list
        <button className="palletSaveButton" onClick={handleSave}> Save </button>
    )
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    let list = [{...}]
    let item = {...}
    
    function handleSaveClick() {
        list.push(item)
    }
    
    return (
        <childComponent handleSave={handleSaveClick} />
    );
}
```

If you simply are looking to click a button on the child, and the logic/values are store in the parent, this should solve your problem. But there's a feeling I'm getting that you are trying to manipulate the variables from the child and send those to the parent.

Comment: I have a similar setup but want to outsource ```handleSaveClick``` to another file as I'm using it in different components. How can I pass the props ```list``` and ```item```?

Comment: UseContext could be a good fit here, or redux/other solution as well